# PermanentRedirect Exception: aws-sdk s3 Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to list or retrieve objects from an amazon bucket and I keep getting this error message:

```
(byebug) resp = s3.list_objects(bucket:'mp3list')
*** Aws::S3::Errors::PermanentRedirect Exception: 
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed 
using the specified endpoint. 
Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

I can upload and delete files from the same bucket with no problem.

Does someone know how to specify that endpoint? and where?

My configuration of the s3 bucket:

```
Bucket: mp3play
Region: Frankfurt
Creation Date:  Fri Dec 09 17:44:39 GMT+100 2016
Owner: aaa

Can list, upload, delete.
```

aws.rb >

```
Aws.config.update({
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']),
  region: 'eu-central-1'
})

# list buckets in Amazon S3
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
resp = s3.list_buckets
S3_BUCKET = resp.buckets[0]
resp.buckets.map(&:name)

S3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'eu-central-1')
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `endpoint` key to config:

```
Aws.config.update({
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']),
  region: 'eu-central-1',
  endpoint:'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'
})
```

The list of available endpoints by regions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region